# Run some code at the end of UIBezierPath addLineToPoint

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to run some script after addLineToPoint of UIBezierPath animation is done.

This is the piece of my code

```
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    CGRect pathRect = CGRectInset(self.animationLayer.bounds, 0.0f, 0.0f);    
// define cgpoint
    CGPoint number1 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(pathRect), CGRectGetMaxY(pathRect));
    [path addLineToPoint: number1];
```

Here I found the reference for UIBezierClass, but I can't find any indicator that animation addLineToPoint is done. Thanks in advance.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I think you need multithread's help

Comment: hm, do you have maybe some solution. So, one thread for the UIBezierPath, and when that thread is done, I should start thread with animation?

Comment: any advice or example of doing this?

Comment: @boban0987: I think you may be misunderstanding the UIBezierPath class slightly. The code you posted won't draw anything to the screen; all you've done at this point is define a path object. If you want your path to show up, you need to invoke `-stroke` or `-fill` on the constructed path within a view's `-drawRect:` method.

Comment: What is the actual question here?  (You say you want to "run some code" but all you look like you're doing is creating a path object.)

Comment: after this is done: [path addLineToPoint: number1];
I want to run some function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no animation involved in `addLineToPoint`. The same is true for all the other methods for constructing a UIBezierPath.

If you check the documentation the method you are talking about is under the section "**Constructing a Path**". All it does is add a line to the point in the model (it's not even drawn on screen yet).

You can draw the entire bezier path by calling `fill` or `stroke` on it inside a `drawRect:`method of some view but that won't animate anything either.

---

It sounds to me that you want to both animate the stroking of that path and get a callback when it is done. If so, you should create a CAShapeLayer and assign your bezier path to its path property. Then you can animate the stroking of that shape layer by animating the `strokeEnd` property from 0 to 1. If you configure yourself to be the delegate of that animation then you will get a `animationDidStop:finished:` callback once the animation is finished.